# Chrome remote devices only detects android phone with android studio open

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, remote-debugging

I have already started developing an android app in the past and I found today that we can inspect a page on the browser of a remote device using the Remote devices tool on Chrome Dev Tools.

To my surprise, my Android device wasn't being recognized in the Remote devices tab on Chrome, despite having already been detected previously in Android Studio in the past.

I opened Android Studio to test if I could still deploy the app on the Android phone and... I could. And now I noticed that the phone was recognized in Chrome... WHAT?!

I closed Android Studio and it went away again. When reopening Android Studio the phone isn't detected by Remote devices imediatly, it is only detected after I click run and the Select Deployment Target window appears.

I suspect it has something to do with the initialization of the ADB, but I don't know what that is, it only says it is initializing when I click run on Android Studio. When Android Studio is closed I guess that is also closed and I need it to be running at all times. How can I keep it running outside of Android Studio and am I really supposed to be doing it or do I have something installed incorrectly?

Details:

Computer OS: Windows 10

Computer Chrome version: 70.0.3538.77

Android OS version: 7.0.0; SM-A520F Build/NRD90M

Android Chrome version: 70.0.3538.64

Android Studio Version: 3.2

EDIT: Ok, so I downloaded the android standalone platform-tools from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

And ran a command line inside the downloaded folder and these were the results:

`C:\Users\rmarques\Desktop\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
521008c4650534ed        device`

So the problem is that the daemon is not running. After I close the command line it keeps running and my phone is still being recognized on remote devices.
I understand that having a daemon start on boot every time may not be the best practice but it should start when I connect my phone using USB right?

EDIT2: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3 doesn't even mention needing SDK tools or ADB or whatever, only the Drivers of the phone and minimum chrome versions/android OS.

Answer (score 1):

On chrome uncheck "Discover USB devices" on Settings of Remote devices found after clicking escape and on the console on the bottom.

cd into the folder where adb.exe is on android platform tools folder.

Start adb server (`adb start-server`)

Unlock phone, connect USB port.

Wait some time after the prompt asking for authentication comes and then press ok, don't click "allow always" as phone's ip change in future will create issues, if you want to use tcp ip mode.

Check on chrome remote devices menu if phone is connected or not. If not connected and 
green is not showing start over by killing adb server (`adb kill-server`)

---

**Optional**

To additionally not use USB cable all the time, use tcp ip mode. If device ip don't change then you'd be so lucky that even after restart of windows device your phone will be able to be debugged by chrome remote devices.

While connected to USB debugging, start at tcp ip mode (`adb tcpip 5555`)

Wait some time and accept ok on prompt, see if device is connected on chrome.

Disconnect USB.

Start command for connecting to phone using phone's ip and port of tcp ip mode(5555) (`adb connect 192.168.123.456:5555`)

Wait some time and accept ok on prompt, see if device is connected on chrome.
If failed to connect comes, then rerun the same connect ip:port command, phone auth prompt should come. wait some time then click ok.

If successful, starting same command to connect using phone's ip should say already connected.

If this method don't work then on Android phone, revoke USB debugging authorizations and start over after killing adb server.